# Remove many packages via Kubuntu software center with only one password entry?

Tags: kubuntu, software-center, password

Some time ago I installed a whole bunch of games on my computer (from the command line) so I could check out what sort of games are available for Linux.  (Probably hundreds of games, in perhaps half a dozen software bundles.)

Now I'd like to do some cleanup.  I'm also trying to stick to the GUI wherever possible in general, as I want to recommend Kubuntu to family members and friends, and would like to have an experience similar to what theirs will be and be able to answer their questions.

Going through and removing packages one by one from the "installed" tab works okay, but I have to type in my password every time.  Worse, I have to *wait* until one package removal finishes before the next password prompt will pop up.  (So I can't click "remove" for several packages and then walk away and let the computer finish.)

(As a side note, it doesn't seem possible to view the installed software *by categories*; only to view installed AND uninstalled software together by categories, or to view ALL installed software in one giant list.  I would like to be wrong about that; please mention it if I am.)

How can I remove many applications via the GUI without having to type my password many times?

Comment: You haven't provided a release, but I'd try muon package manager  (this is suggestion only, as I'd use `aptitude` in a terminal and in interactive mode (ie. `sudo aptitude`). but `muon` would be my first suggestion for KDE/Kubuntu/LXQt/Lubuntu)

Comment: +1 for muon. It's quite similar to Synaptic Package Manager.

Comment: @guiverc thanks, that's useful but I see that Muon doesn't display the application icons, which makes it much harder to use for this specific purpose.

Comment: It doesn't seem likely that your loved ones will install hundreds of packages using the command line but want to remove them using a GUI method. My experience providing support for family members for a decade is that most don't install anything. Those few that do rarely encounter problems installing software. Even fewer try to uninstall anything.

Comment: **1**: You have been asked to provide your version of Kubuntu. Please do so. Also, depending on which repositories are installed you may have newer software. **2**: So please also provide the output of `plasmashell --version`. You seem to want to use "Discover" which is under rapid development. Hence, the information would be helpful. **3**: Since you've used the command line, add the commands you used to install the various bundles.

Comment: Be aware that whether icons are visible in Discover may depend on the applications being "appstream-compliant". Also be aware that Discover may not show all the packages seen by, say, `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall`.

Comment: @guiverc `apper`, in the repos, will let you filter for installed games, select several for deletion, and then apply the changes. So the password has to be provided just once. And for the games installed by default on Kubuntu 20.04, icons are visible as well. Take a look at it: it shouldn't pull in too many dependencies in Lubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @DKBose, I just updated; I am using Kubuntu 20.04.  Plasmashell 5.18.4.  The bundles were installed over a year ago; I don't have the commands.

Comment: **1**: Questions about 20.04 are currently **off-topic**. See *Questions that you should avoid:* [in here](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). **2**: Re. installing games on multiple machines,  I'd be very cautious. How any game performs may depend on each computer's resources (RAM, CPU, GPU, etc). So what works on one may not work on another.

Comment: @DKBose, got it; however, since this isn't about something *broken* in 20.04 but rather about a missing feature, the version is really irrelevant.  The exact same question and missing feature still applies to 18.04.  Wait a couple weeks and the question will be on-topic, without changing a single word.  I feel your attitude is a little combative rather than attempting to be helpful.  Maybe take a break from commenting?  :)

Comment: @DKBose, on reflection, I think I may have been hasty myself.  Sorry about that!  I do understand the terseness (it wasn't rudeness) that can come from steadily dealing with clueless questioners on a volunteer basis.  Thanks for your input and expertise!  I've put in countless hours on U&L myself so I know how it goes; sorry for being "that guy."

Comment: Incidentally, I had actually attempted to install 19.10, but the `do-release-upgrade` did nothing and `do-release-upgrade -d` took me straight to 20.04 and I didn't realize until it had finished.  Anyway, I *would* welcome and appreciate your expertise on any future questions; I humbly apologize and retract my comment.  (Feel free to delete or clean up this comment thread as you see fit, once you read it.)

Comment: No problem at all. I understand your point of view. I'll remove this comment later.

Answer (score 1):

Synaptic Package Manager, which can be installed alongside another software center, allows the user to install/uninstall multiple packages with a single click. You don't need to authenticate with your user password to install/uninstall multiple packages except for once each time before launching Synaptic. To install Synaptic on all currently supported versions of Ubuntu/Kubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install synaptic
```

[image: Package search by section type in Synaptic]
<sup>**Package search by section type in Synaptic**</sup>

The *Origin* button in the left pane of Synaptic allows the user to search for packages filtered by their software source.